# Assume that the order of $a$ in $ \pmod n$ is $h$ and the order of $b$ in $ \pmod n$ is $k$. Show that the order of $ab$ in $ \mod n$ divides $hk$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume that the order of $a$ in $ \pmod n$ is $h$ and the order of $b$ in $ \pmod n$ is $k$.
 Show that the order of $ab$ in  $ \mod n$ divides $hk$

---

$  a^h \equiv 1 \pmod n $
$ b^k \equiv 1 \pmod n $

$\implies $
$  a^hb^k \equiv 1 \pmod n $

How to proceed from here ?

Comment: $$(ab)^{kh}=(a^h)^k(b^k)^h\equiv1^h1^k\pmod n$$  But ord$_n(ab)|hk$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply note that $(a b)^{hk} = a^{hk} b^{hk} = (a^{h})^{k} (b^{k})^{h} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, whence the order of $ab$ divides $hk$.

You are using the fact that for an element $g$ of finite order $t$ of a group $G$ the following are equivalent, for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$,

1. $a^{z} = 1$, and
2. $t$ divides $z$.

Comment: how to move from $a^h b^k$ to $(ab)^{hk}$ ? could you please elaborate

Comment: @rational, just did.

Comment: Wow! I get it, thanks a lot!!